# Prove $-12^{482}$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo 175

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As in the title, I'm trying to prove $-12^{482}$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo 175. Generally, I believe I could do this by showing that $gcd(-12^{482}, 175)=1$, (i.e that they're relatively prime) but I'm not sure about how to deal with the exponent without fully computing $-12^{482}$.

Comment: Do you think that $2^{100}$ is relatively prime to $5$?

Comment: Yes. That helps.

Comment: More explicitly, since $$12 = 2^2 \times 3^1,$$ $$12^{(482)} = 2^{(482) \times 2} \times 3^{(482) \times 1}.$$  Thus, the only prime factors in $12^{(482)}$ are $2$ and $3$.  Both $2$ and $3$ are relatively prime to $(175) = 5^2 \times 7.$

Comment: Yes, $a$ is invertible mod $n\iff a$ is coprime to $n$, and coprimes to $n$ are closed under product by the linked dupe, so it suffices to show that $12$ (and $-1$) are coprime to $175\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^k$ is invertible modulo $n$ iff $x$ is. This is because $x$ and $x^k$ have the same prime factors, just with different multiplicities.

In your case, $n = 175 = 5^2 \cdot 7$ while $x = 12 = 2^2 \cdot 3$ are coprime.

Answer (score 1):

By [Fermat-Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) $12^{120}=1$, so the inverse is $-12^{118}$.